# Jquery Dynamically set select options according to other select value

Tags: jquery

I am trying to set up a short form that will have each select box populate the next.

The first select box options are coded in the body, the rest are coded as an html string in a variable that matches the option values in the first drop down.
It doesn't seem to recognise the selected value as being a reference to the variable containing the HTML string to load.
How do I get it to recognise the select value as being the string to load?

I expect it to load the relevant string as HTML into the `PathwaySubGroup` drop down.

```html
<div id="PathwayAssignment">
  <a>Pathway Group</a>
  <select id="PathwayGroup">
    <option value="Pway1">NonPsychotic</option>
    <option value="Pway2">Psychotic</option>
    <option value="Pway3">Dementia</option>
    <option value="Pway4">Personality Disorder</option>
    <option value="Pway5">Other</option>
  </select>

  <a>Pathway Sub Group</a>
  <select id="PathwaySubGroup">
  </select>
</div>
```

```js
Var Pway1 = '<option value="1">Depression</option><option value="2">Generalised Anxiety</option><option value="3">Panic Disorder</option><option value="4">Phobias</option><option value="5">PTSD</option><option value="6">Dissociative disorders</option><option value="7">Somatoform disorders</option><option value="7">Eating disorders</option>';

Var Pway2 = '<option value="8">Bipolar</option><option value="9">Schizophrenia</option><option value="10">Psychotic disorder NOS</option><option value="11">Delusional disorder</option><option value="12">Schizoaffective disorder</option><option value="13">Shizoid/Paranoid personality disorder</option>';

$("#PathwayGroup").change(function() {
  var PW = this.value
  $("#PathwaySubGroup").html(PW);
```

Comment: Note that JS is case sensitive, so `Var` is not the same as `var` and will be causing an error. Check the console to debug this.

Comment: if you wanted to do it this way you would need to use `eval` but I would recommend against that and instead use an array like `ar['Pway1'] = ...` and then get the value using `ar[PW]` or `ar[this.value]`

Comment: Unrelated: Both 'Eating disorders' and 'Somatoform disorders' have the same value (7).

Answer (score 0):

Get the id of the selected option, then hide or show values in the second dropdown.

```
<div id="PathwayAssignment">
<a>Pathway Group</a>
<select id="PathwayGroup">
    <option value="Pway1">NonPsychotic</option>
    <option value="Pway2">Psychotic</option>
</select>

<a>Pathway Sub Group</a>
<select id="PathwaySubGroup1">
    <option value="PSubgroup1" id="PSubgroup1">NonPsychotic</option>
    <option value="PSubgroup2" id="PSubgroup2">Psychotic</option>
</select>
</div>



<script type="text/javascript">
$('#PathwayGroup').on('change', function(){

    if( $(this).val() == 'Pway1' ){
        $('#PSubgroup1').hide();
        $('#PSubgroup2').show();
    } else if( $(this).val() == 'Pway2' ){
        $('#PSubgroup1').show();
        $('#PSubgroup2').hide();
    }

}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add your Pway vars to an array with named keys.

```
var options = [];
options['Pway1'] = '<option value="1">Depression</option><option value="2">Generalised Anxiety</option><option value="3">Panic Disorder</option><option value="4">Phobias</option><option value="5">PTSD</option><option value="6">Dissociative disorders</option><option value="7">Somatoform disorders</option><option value="7">Eating disorders</option>';
options['Pway2'] = '<option value="8">Bipolar</option><option value="9">Schizophrenia</option><option value="10">Psychotic disorder NOS</option><option value="11">Delusional disorder</option><option value="12">Schizoaffective disorder</option><option value="13">Shizoid/Paranoid personality disorder</option>';
```

the only change to your .change event would be to retreive the right value of the array.

```
$("#PathwaySubGroup").html(options[this.value]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var Pway1 = 'DepressionGeneralised AnxietyPanic DisorderPhobiasPTSDDissociative disordersSomatoform disordersEating disorders';

var Pway2 = 'BipolarSchizophreniaPsychotic disorder NOSDelusional disorderSchizoaffective disorderShizoid/Paranoid personality disorder';

$("#PathwayGroup").change(function () {
  $("#PathwaySubGroup").html("");
  var text = window[this.value];
  $("#PathwaySubGroup").append('<option value="">' + text + '</option>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Pathway Group</div>
<select id="PathwayGroup">
  <option value="" selected disabled>Chose a pathway group</option>
  <option value="Pway1">NonPsychotic</option>
  <option value="Pway2">Psychotic</option>
  <option value="Pway3">Dementia</option>
  <option value="Pway4">Personality Disorder</option>
  <option value="Pway5">Other</option>
</select>

<div>Pathway Sub Group</div>
<select id="PathwaySubGroup"></select>
```